# Why does my Expression Tree create a variable instead of setting the LabelTarget directly?

Tags: c#, lambda, expression, expression-trees, func

I have the "problem" with the following expression tree that it creates a local variable inside the "Try" instead of setting the value directly for the LabelTarget. It's not necessarily a problem, yet I would like to understand why this happens and if I can somehow prevent the creation of the local variable as well.

**Expression Tree:**

```
var returnTarget = Expression.Label(typeof(string), "value");
var instanceArgument = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "instance");
var instanceAsType = Expression.Convert(instanceArgument, propertyInfo.DeclaringType);

var propertyValueAsType = Expression.Property(instanceAsType, propertyInfo.Name);

var exceptionParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Exception), "exception");
Expression tryCatch = Expression.TryCatch(
        Expression.Label(
            returnTarget,
            Expression.Call(
                typeof(Enum).GetMethod("GetName", new[] { typeof(Type), typeof(object) }),
                Expression.Constant(propertyInfo.PropertyType),
                Expression.Convert(propertyValueAsType, typeof(object)))),
        Expression.Catch(
            exceptionParameter,
            Expression.Label(
                returnTarget,
                Expression.Property(
                    exceptionParameter,
                    "Message"))));

return Expression.Lambda<Func<object, object>>(tryCatch, instanceArgument);
```

**Resulting code:**

```
public static object getValue_Enum(object instance)
{
    string message;
    try
    {
        // This should not happen. Instead, it should directly assign the value to "message"
        string name = Enum.GetName((RuntimeType)typeof(Program.TestEnum), ((Program.Test2)instance).get_Enum()); 
        message = name;
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        message = exception.Message;
    }
    return message;
}
```

Comment: You have to put `TryCatch` into `Expression.Block` with declared variable.

Comment: And actually I do not see reason why do you build such expression tree.

Comment: And which variable should I declare in the block? "returnTarget" does not work, because it must be of type ParameterExpression. "exceptionParameter" works, but doesn't make sense (doesn't change the resulting code either). Creating a new variable only causes another variable to be created. But I want to set the value directly for "returnTarget". In the CatchBlock it works correctly, the value is assigned directly to "returnTarget". Why not in the Try block?

Comment: And to answer your question, right now I'm just playing around with this to learn about it. Later this will probably be used, as I need to dynamically retrieve and store all values for all properties of an object, where the type is not known at compile time.